# Unweighted directed graph dfs_iterator operator++ C++

Tags: c++, graph, depth-first-search

I am working on the construction of the graph (unweighted, directed) class that accepts `dfs_iterator` and `bfs_iterator` with operations `++` to move to next value, `*` to get current vertex, `==` and `!=` to compare the vertices. I am implementing the code in C++. The graph class is implemented using an adjacency list and it has private members `vector<VType> vertices`, `vector<list<size_t>> adj_list` and member functions `add_vertex(vertex)`, `add_edge(index1, index2)`, `remove_edge(index1, index2)`, `get_vertex(index)`, `has_edge(index1, index2)`, `get_neighbors(index)` etc., and within the graph class I've implemented `dfs_iterator` class that does `++`, `*`, `==`, `!=` operations. Below is the code I am trying to implement.

```
class graph {
private:
   std::vector<VType> vertices;
   std::vector<std::list<std::size_t>> adj_list;
public:
//... other member function implementations ...//
  class dfs_iterator {
  private:
        std::vector<std::list<std::size_t >> adjList;     // to hold the adj_list of graph class 
        std::vector<VType> vertexProp;               //to hold the vertices of graph class
        std::size_t index;                                // to keep track of current index
        std::list<std::size_t>::iterator li_it;           // to handle the list of each adjList[index]
  public:
     dfs_iterator(std::vector<std::list<std::size_t >> adj_list_, std::vector<VType> vertex_props_, std::size_t start_idx) {
            this->adjList = adj_list_;
            this->vertexProp = vertex_props_;
            this->index = start_idx;
            this->li_it = adjList[index].begin();

        };

        VType &operator*() {
            return vertexProp[index];
        };

        dfs_iterator &operator++() {               // explanation in the description below
            if (this->li_it != adjList[index].end()) { // iterating over the depth until we hit the leaf with zero elements
               this->index = *li_it;              // jumping to index of list element
               li_it = adjList[index].begin();    // changing the li_it to new list
            } else {                             
              /*  have to handle the cases where we hit the end and search from a new branch of the parent and keep doing all the possible paths are closed. */
            }
            return *this;
        };
    };

    dfs_iterator dfs_begin(std::size_t vertex_idx) {
        return dfs_iterator(adj_list, vertices, vertex_idx);
    };

    dfs_iterator dfs_end(std::size_t vertex_idx) {
        return dfs_iterator(adj_list, vertices, vertex_idx);;
    };
  }
}
```

Now, my `*` oepration works as expected but the `++` operator has few issues.
if my adjacency list is as mentioned below:

```
**index. list_of_neighbours/edges**
   0. {4, 2, 6, 8}
   1. {3, 5}
   2. {}
   3. {7}
   4. {3}
   5. {}
   6. {}
   7. {8}
   8. {}
```

on doing

```
    string delim = "";
    for (auto it = graph.dfs_begin(0); it != graph.dfs_end(8); ++it) {
        cout << delim << *it;
        delim = " -> ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
```

my output is:

```
Traversing the graph in depth first fashion:
0 -> 4 -> 3 -> 7
```

as expected. but if in the `0`th index, instead of `{4, 2, 6, 8}` my neighbors list is `{2, 4, 6, 8}`, then my `operator++` on checking the list in index `2`, which is dead, it should retreat from proceeding further and start from `2`nd item of `0`th index, i.e., `4` and dfs `0 -> 4 -> 3 -> 7`.

I am looking for any suggestions or tips that help me proceed further. Open to answer further queries.

Comment: First, I think it would be better for your iterator to hold a reference to the graph and not copy all members, this makes the iterator quite heavy-weight. Regarding your logic: You are not tracking, which nodes you visited. This means, if you had a loop in your graph, you would start to cycle. For a non-recursive dfs, one generally uses a stack to hold the next nodes you want to visit, I would recommend doing that here to. I don't think working with the list-iterator will be a comfortable way to do that.

Comment: Thank you, your comment really helped me. I used the stack to track the parent node in the dfs and queue in bfs and it perfectly worked. :)